# Run Django and Node in a Heroku app simultaneously

Tags: python, django, node.js, heroku

I would like to run a django application and a node app on my heroku instance at the same time.

Here is my procfile:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
web: node bin/node_modules/app.js
```

However, as I anticipated, it looks as though this only runs the node app. Is it possible to configure Heroku to run both of these processes in the same procfile, or do I need to do something else? (If something else, what? I would prefer not to have an entirely separate heroku instance).

and you know, because Heroku's port variable is entirely internal, I could do something like pass node app.js port = $PORT, which I don't mind, but I would still like to accomplish having them both in the same spot.

Comment: This isn't working because you're overriding the value of the 'web' procfile type. If you want to run them both separately (on different dynos), you can do so by giving each a name (eg: `python` and `node`), then run `heroku scale python=1 node=1`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party but Heroku just posted a blog post about how to accomplish this.

Read it [here](https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2014-10-29-heroku-django-node), but essentially, you'll use this [custom buildpack](https://github.com/dpiddy/heroku-buildpack-runit) to have a sub-procfile setup like so:

Procfile:

```
web: bin/runsvdir-dyno
```

Procfile.web:

```
django: gunicorn path.to.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:$DJANGO_PORT
node: node server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need two different process names:

```
webpy: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
webjs: node bin/node_modules/app.js
```

(Assuming each process works properly otherwise)

Comment: This got me close, but really I just added to web: references ad heroku ps:scale web=2 to add another web dyno.

Answer (score 0):

Can't post a comment yet, but have you tried:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT & node bin/node_modules/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment, you need to scale your apps process manager to include two dynos if you want two web processes:

```
heroku ps:scale web=2
```