# How can I run multiple apps which that accept requests in Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, devops

Is it possible to configure Heroku where one has two processes that accept HTTP requests?

I would like to run one traditional request/response process (perhaps a Django Gunicorn process), and also run a NodeJS service that provides web-sockets. It would be nice if I could configure Heroku to work to a routing pattern like this:

```
ws/                                         # NodeJS websocket process
*                                           # Django Process
```

Where any request with a URL begining with `ws/` gets routed to the NodeJS websocket process, and everything else gets routed to Django.

---

Heroku gives an example of something similar.

> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/realtime-polyglot-app-node-ruby-mongodb-socketio

But I really do not like this approach and will only consider it as a last resort. The issue is that the NodeJS process and the Rails process, are in separate Heroku apps. This will cause hassle when it comes to billing versioning and staging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Django and Node in a Heroku app simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565808/run-django-and-node-in-a-heroku-app-simultaneously)